# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in Yii2 , CreateCommand

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, yii2

I use Yii2.

in this query i have error:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE post SET text2 = :text2 WHERE id=4",
    [':text2' => htmlspecialchars_decode(':text2')])->queryAll();
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
>
> > ```
> > The SQL being executed was: UPDATE post SET text2 = text2 WHERE id=4
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query  it will work fine

```
$text2 = htmlspecialchars_decode(YOUR TEXT2 value)

Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE post SET text2 = '$text2' WHERE id=:id")->bindValues(array(':id' => 4))->execute();
```

Comment: i need value text2

Comment: value text2 encode html , i need value text2 decode html

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode will give you the decode html value you just need to put your encoded html value inside this function

Comment: yes you right , but i need value field text2 for replace with text2

Comment: As per my understanding you want to update text2 column with your input value

Comment: your code:  $text2 = htmlspecialchars_decode(YOUR TEXT2 value) , i dont have (YOUR TEXT2 value) before update , i need in Update query TEXT2 value deocoded and replace with TEXT2. in ONE query